# Extracting CSV from Quicksight dashboard using Python

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-quicksight

I can manually access some Quicksight dashboards and hit "export to CSV", but I want to automate that task (as it is the first of many steps to updating some reports). Can this be done automatically using Python?

Note: I did not create the dashboards in Quicksight, I just have privileges to see them.

Answer (score -3):

Since you approach datasets stored in a different locations (quicksight is injected with them, from S3, Athena tables etc., exporting from quicksight is not the way. if you'll know location of dataset/datasource, go there. for example, S3 to csv